# Summing binary tree levels

Tags: java

I'm trying to traverse a binary tree by level, then sum the ints held in each node per level which is held in levelSum. I then want to multiply the levelSum by the number of the level that I am at and add this to the totalSum. When I run it I get a NullPointException on line 15 but I haven't been able to figure out why.

```
public int depthSum() {
    Queue<IntTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<IntTreeNode>();
    int totalSum = 0;
    int levelSum = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;
    int nodesPerLevel = 0;
    if(overallRoot != null) {
        q.offer(overallRoot);
        nodesPerLevel += 1;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            int countDown = nodesPerLevel;
            while(countDown > 0) {
                countDown--;
                IntTreeNode n = q.remove();
                levelSum += n.data; //this is line 15
                if(n.left != null) {
                    q.offer(n.left);
                    nodesPerLevel++;
                }
                if(n.right != null) {
                    q.offer(n.right);
                    nodesPerLevel++;
                }
            }
            totalSum += (multiplier * levelSum);
            levelSum = 0;
            multiplier++;
        }
    }
    return totalSum
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
NullPointerException on line 15:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at IntTree.depthSum (Line 15)
```

Comment: As always: Stacktrace please. And which line is line 15?

Comment: Is this line 15 : `tempSum += n.data;`?

Comment: Yes, that's line 15. Just added a comment to show it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: where is tempSum declared?

Comment: Well, if `tempSum += n.data` throws an NPE, then obviously `n` is `null`, which means that `q.remove()` returned `null`, which means that the queue was empty. OH ... just saw: If `tempSum` is of type `Integer` and was not initialized, this could also be `null`. Is it declared as an instance field? If yes, remove it and use a local variable instead.

Comment: tempSum should have been levelSum. This didn't fix the problem though. I check that the root is not null in the first conditional statement, then put it into the queue. When I make the new IntTreeNode n and assign it to the node in the queue it shouldn't be null right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, probably `countdown` does not hold the correct value; however, given that a lot of the variables are undefined in the code it is hard to tell exactly where the failure is.

If `countdown` is faulty, the inner loop will  eventually empty the queue. When this happens you will get `n = null`, and trying to call `n.data`, `n.left`, or `n.right` will give a `NullPointerException`.

Below is a similar version of what I think you are trying to do ([**Ideone example here**](https://ideone.com/TJsxSJ)):

```
public int depthSum(IntTreeNode root) {
    if(root == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    Queue<IntTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<IntTreeNode>();
    q.add(root);
    int siblings = 1;
    int totalSum = 0, levelSum = 0, level = 0;

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        IntTreeNode n = q.remove();            // Only remove one node per loop
        levelSum += n.data;

        if(n.left != null)                     // Add left child 
            q.add(n.left);

        if(n.right != null)                    // Add right child
            q.add(n.right);

        if(--siblings == 0){                   // All siblings have been probed
            siblings = q.size();               // All remaining Nodes are siblings
            totalSum += levelSum * level;      // increment totalSum
            level++;                           // increment level
            levelSum = 0;                      // reinitialize levelSum
        }
    }
    return totalSum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The main point for NullPointException should be nodesPerLevel not reset to 0; countDown should be larger than the queue size and causes q.remove throw NullPointException.

nodesPerLevel should reset to 0 just after countDown = nodesPerLevel.

this code snippet looks unable to compile, e.g. tempSum looks to be levelSum. so the finally result sill need verification.

Comment: `nodesPerLevel` could never give `NPE` in this code because its type is primitive type.

Comment: @Andremoniy, thanks for your comments, I am glad my answer got response. you're right that **nodePerLevel** not give **NPE**. but since **nodesPerLevel** not reset to **0**, it will be greater than the size of of **q** and cause **q.remove** throw **NPE**.